# How much evidence exists that this patent actually belonged to the owner of record?

Tags: us613819, tesla

In reference to the patent: [US613819](https://www.google.com/patents/US613819)

Various patent logs report this patent as belonging to Nikola Tesla under the heading "Filings Tube", such as "Wireless telegraphy; its origins, development, inventions, and apparatus". New York, D. Van Nostrand company, 1903. LCCN 03026887 written by Charles Henry Sewall.  Can anyone expand on this discrepancy?

Answer (score 1):

I can see a few options, which I present in order of decreasing likelihood. Of course, perhaps we'll never know for sure.

**Sewall made a mistake in his book**

After a bit of a search around, every reference I could find to Tesla having US 613,819 seems to stem from that 1903 Sewall book. Could this have simply been a mistake in the book?

Tesla is recorded as the inventor of [US 613,809](https://www.google.com/patents/US613809) (albeit with a different title) (as noted by some chap at the [Australian Nikola Tesla Society](http://www.pupman.com/listarchives/1996/may/msg00260.html) in a message many years ago).

The chance that Tesla was granted two patents which differed by one digit, and that subsequently one was disappeared (for whatever reason) seems vanishingly small, compared to the chance that an author 113 years ago made a typo.

**The USPTO made a mistake in its patent numbering**

This is possible: there are multiple patents numbered 1, and a few patents with fractional numbers (noted by the [USPTO](https://www.uspto.gov/sites/default/files/web/patents/authority/patentlayoutv4.txt)). Thus mistakes (or at least unusual choices) have been made in the past.

It therefore seems within the realm of possibility that a patent number was assigned twice, such that one of the patents with that number is now unrecorded.

**There was a cover-up by the US government!**

I guess it's not completely impossible. But I couldn't find any evidence of this (which perhaps is evidence that the cover-up was done well). But in any case, if the US government wanted to cover-up the invention, surely they would just not issue the patent in the first place.

Comment: Thank you for the research.  The item patented was not earth shaking in design so I also doubt a cover-up.